# Window object ScrollworkbookTabs function issue

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA code is for an application that does a side-by-side comparison of two worksheets in the same Excel 2010 workbook. The code achieves it's purpose, but has some strange side effects:

- Without the Activate and Select statements, the `ScrollWorkbookTabs` function executes without an error, but doesn't actually open the next workbook tab in `window(1)`
- When I include the Activate and Select statements, the `ScrollWorkbookTabs` function executes correctly and opens the next tab in window(1), but the cursor in window(1) isn't erased-and-redrawn correctly when moving from cell-to-cell.

I need to have the `ScrollWorkbookTabs` function work and the cursor to redraw correctly.

Are there any circumstance where `ScrollWorkbookTabs` will not work as advertised? Is it possible to affect how the cursor is redrawn by the window?

[image]

```
   'xlt.Activate
   'xlt.Range("K558").Select
   xlb.Windows(1).Caption = xlt.Name
   xlb.Windows(1).ScrollWorkbookTabs Sheets:=1
   xlb.Windows(1).ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 10, 10
   If xlb.Windows.Count < 2 Then
      xlb.Windows(1).NewWindow ' New window is automatically the active one
      xlb.Windows(1).Caption = xls.Name
      xlb.Windows(1).ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 10, 10
   End If
   xlb.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith (xlt.Name)
   xlb.Windows.SyncScrollingSideBySide = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that Excel thinks the cursor is visible when it actually isn't. In this state, toggling the cursor causes it to always be in the wrong state in that window i.e. Excel thinking that it's visible when it's not, and invisible when it is visible. Activating the sheets in this order seems to have fixed the problem.

```
xlt.Activate
xls.Activate
xlb.Windows(1).Caption = xlt.Name
xlb.Windows(1).ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 10, 10
If xlb.Windows.Count < 2 Then
   xlb.Windows(1).NewWindow ' New window is automatically the active one
   xlb.Windows(1).Caption = xls.Name
   xlb.Windows(1).ScrollIntoView 1, 1, 10, 10
End If
xlb.Windows.CompareSideBySideWith (xlt.Name)
xlb.Windows.SyncScrollingSideBySide = True
```